# Using a shared Weka Classifier in a multi threaded application results with Exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, weka

I'm running a multi-threaded Java application which gets requests to classify instances. In order to be able to run many threads concurrently my application shares a `Classifier` object and an `Instances` object among the threads. The Instances object contains only attributes' related data and does not have any instance associated with it.

When my application gets a classification request, I create an `Instance` object with the request's attributes data and set the pre-generated `Instances` object as the dataset using `Instance.setDataset()`, e.g.:

```
myNewInstance.setDataset(sharedInstances);
```

Then `myNewInstance` is sent to the shared `Classifier`.

It seems to work well in most cases. However sometimes when 2 concurrent requests occur, an exception is thrown from `Classifier.distributionForInstance()`. Unfortunately the error message is not clear, however these are 2 different exceptions I see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Queue is empty
at weka.core.Queue.pop(Queue.java:194)
at weka.filters.Filter.output(Filter.java:563)
at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.PrincipalComponents.convertInstance(PrincipalComponents.java:626)
at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.PrincipalComponents.input(PrincipalComponents.java:812)
at weka.classifiers.meta.RotationForest.convertInstance(RotationForest.java:1114)
at weka.classifiers.meta.RotationForest.distributionForInstance(RotationForest.java:1147)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize.convertInstance(Standardize.java:238)
at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize.input(Standardize.java:142)
at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.PrincipalComponents.convertInstance(PrincipalComponents.java:635)
at weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.PrincipalComponents.input(PrincipalComponents.java:812)
at weka.classifiers.meta.RotationForest.convertInstance(RotationForest.java:1114)
at weka.classifiers.meta.RotationForest.distributionForInstance(RotationForest.java:1147)
```

As you can see, when the latest happens it comes with an empty message string.

To my understanding I can't make the objects immutable, and I'd rather not wrap this part in a critical section in order to utilize the most out of the concurrency.
I've tried creating a different 'Instances' object per each classification request by using the constructor `Instances(Instances dataset)`, however, it did not yield different results. Using a different `Classifier` is not an option since it takes too much time to construct the object and it needs to respond fast (10 to 20 milliseconds at most), and to my understanding the problem does not rely there.

I assume that the problem comes from using the same Instances object. Based on the documentation of [Instances](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html) the constructor only copies the references to the header information which explains why the problem was not solved by creating another object. Is there an option to create a completely different Instances object based on a previous object without going over all attributes in realtime?

Any other performance-oriented solution will also be highly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Probably you have solved this issue by now. This is just for those who face a similar issue. I was testing instances in a multi-threaded Java application, and I faced the same exception. To break down the problem, there are two issues in your case:

- The first one is that you are using the same `Instances` object where you are setting the data for each request. With this, you will most probably run into concurrency issues that might not break the code, but will yield wrong results. Because the data from different requests could get mixed up. Your best bet is to create a new `Instances` object for each request. However, this is not what is producing the exception you are facing. It is the second issue.
- The second issue is that you are using the same `Classifier`, and this is what is producing the exception. In my case I had the classifiers built and serialized and written to a file since I constructed them. Once I need to classify a test set, I used to deserialize the object in each thread, giving me a new instance. However, a proper way to solve this issue would be to use the `weka.classifiers.Classifier.makeCopy(model)` static method to make a copy for each request, which internally uses serialization.